# How do I create a wins-losses-draws table for a sports team using Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor, aggregation-framework

Apologies for this long winded question but I just want to walk through my research into trying to solve this problem myself.

My first stackoverflow question... here goes...

My meteor app was plugging along nicely until I wanted to have a standings table. This [30 years of basketball standings](http://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/crunching-30-years-of-nba-data-with-mongodb-aggregation/) article was inspirational. I wanted to tap into that power and flexibility that Mongo provided and keep track of team and player standings I bought this book on Mongo (highly recommended). I have multiple collections and one collection called 'games' that keeps track of games and scores per game. Here is a same document:

```js
{
    "leagueId" : "6RtH74QbxGG7xbZXh",
    "regionId" : "KDbqfAoKDx2iDDXSS",
    "seasonId" : "b5HkGcWFNenpGGvCd",
    "gameTime" : "15:00",
    "gameDate" : "11/23/2014",
    "gameNumber" : 4,
    "gameStatus" : "played",
    "homeTeam" : "MYBw2RiNwrBhfh9W8",
    "homeTeamScore" : 4,
    "awayTeam" : "fwx79JJFob5XbaAx6",
    "awayTeamScore" : 2,
    "gameType" : "regular_season",
    "userId" : "4MKaZK84AdZ8j3xr2",
    "author" : "league",
    "submitted" : "Wed Dec 10 2014 09:51:48 GMT-0800 (PST)",
    "_id" : "Gwsu6X6DXXzavdqZQ"
}
```

I determined the aggregate framework was the way to go but after digging into this I saw that Meteor had some client side limitations with the mongo aggregate framework (stackoverflow.com/questions/11266977/are-group-by-aggregation-queries-possible-in-meteor-yet).

I also thought about [denormalizing my document structure after reading articles like this][4]. And after reading the Denormalization chapter of Discover Meteor (good book!), it seems not denormalizing gives me a lot more flexibility but I can denormalize in Meteor/Mongo with other benefits. The NBA article mentioned earlier is very denormalized and not sure if I can replicate that structure using Meteor/Mongo.

I then jumped in the Aggregate rabbit hole and found some good reading (stackoverflow.com/questions/18520567/average-aggregation-queries-in-meteor/18884223#18884223 - I tried this using my data and I saw the output on the server but when I added the subscription to 'waiton' in my iron router there were no errors and it just hung. So it worked on the server, not the client?).

[I then found this article which looked very promising](http://joshowens.me/using-mongodb-aggregations-to-power-a-meteor-js-publication/). That led me to the atmosphere package ([meteorhacks:aggregate][8]... and it's dependencies) but the article seemed more directed at experts with mongo as I could not get my data client side.

From all my reading I surmise that I should create a new collection in my 'collections' folder (available on client and server) and then I publish that collection using my aggregate code ($group and $match and cool things like $sum). Then I'm really not sure what to do next. Do I create a server method and call that method from my client side code (tried that and couldn't get it to work)? Am I supposed to subscribe to the collection in iron-router (every time I did, my app just hung with no errors)?

If anyone gets how to use aggregate with meteor I would really appreciate some/any guidance. I think I just need a few more pieces of information before I can generate that standings table with wins, losses and draws.

note: I took a detour and thought MapReduce might be the solution(thebhwgroup.com/blog/2014/09/bi-nodejs-couchdb-mapreduce) but I couldn't get this to work in Meteor either.

Answer (score 0):

You raise a number of topics and there are probably a lot of solutions to get where you want. One key point is that you cannot currently run mongo aggregations on the client side in Meteor. So any approach where you are aggregating game data into standings needs to first aggregate the game data server-side, and only then publish a `cursor` of the results to the client.

To break your problem down into more manageable simples, I would first focus on assembling an aggregation on the server side that looks the way you want. You will need a package such as `meteorhacks:aggregate` as you mentioned, or others that accomplish the same purpose.

Then, for starters, you should simply run the aggregation pipeline server-side on `Meteor.startup` a few times until it looks the way you want. To get a quick look at it, you could save it to a variable and log it in the console (again, server-side). Alternatively, you could save it into a new `Collection` such as `Standings` and inspect it using `meteor mongo` from the console. Part of the issue is that you may be getting ahead of things trying to publish and subscribe to your collections with Iron Router while you are still thinking about how to set up your collections.

This gets to the next point. Once the aggregation document looks the way you want on the server, you'll need to decide whether you want to save the results each time you aggregate a new set of standings, or assemble them on the fly each time you publish it. In the Owens article you linked to, he is aggregating data directly inside of a publish function.  This means it is re-run each time it is published or subscribed to, which could be very fast or very slow depending on the size and complexity of the data. It is also important to consider that under this model you are not actually publishing a collection of standings to the client - you are publishing a mutated collection of games. If you expect your standings to acquire their own properties, change over time, or you want to poll them historically, you are best off creating a new `Collection` such as `Standings` and inserting a new standing into the collection each time you receive new game results.

Your publish function could then be fairly simple, e.g., `Standings.find({}, {limit: 1})` with a query for the most recent standing. You can subscribe in Iron Router's `waitOn` as you suggested.

To insert new entries into the Standings collection, you could call a server side method like `Meteor.Call("createStandings")` each time a new game is introduced. This could result in a large document over time, which you could cull or even write over if you don't care about maintaining historical records.

Again, there are a lot of ways you could take this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Sadly, I still can not get it to work even after much effort. From what I see online, it appears many people are having problems with meteor and aggregation. 

I think the best way to help myself and others with a similar issue with aggregation, I have created a github repo with a starting point and a problem. Here is the link to the repo: [link](https://github.com/kingluddite/agro_aggregation)

If anyone can take a peek and offer tips/suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.